# Access - rank duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need help in access. I have two tables which join on key which is made on 8 columns. Even now I still have duplicates in both tables. To solve that issue I think I should rank those duplicates. 
Could someone help me because I am not able to solve it

at the moment I have only text concat. I need to add number of duplicate 
if value is not duplicated there should be 1 at the end

for ex.

```
SELECT 
table1.ColA, 
table1.ColL, 
table1.ColC, 
table1.ColD, 
table1.ColE, 
table1.ColH, 
table1.ColI, 
table1.ColJ, 
table1.ColK, 
table1.ColL, 
table1.ColO, 
table1.ColP, 
table1.ColR,
table1.ColS, 
table1.INDEXCOL -> how to create number of duplicated values from 8 columns

FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.ColS = table2.ColS) AND (table1.ColC = table2.ColC) AND (table1.ColK = table2.ColK) AND (table1.ColP = table2.ColP) AND (table1.ColO = table2.ColO) AND (table1.ColE = table2.ColE) AND (table1.ColL = table2.ColL)
GROUP BY table1.ColA, table1.ColL, table1.ColC, table1.ColD, table1.ColE, table1.ColH, table1.ColI, table1.ColJ, table1.ColK, table1.ColL, table1.ColO, table1.ColP, table1.ColR, table1.ColS
```

and

```
SELECT 
table2.ColA, 
table2.ColB, 
table2.ColC, 
table2.ColD, 
table2.ColE, 
table2.ColF, 
table2.ColG, 
table2.ColH
table2.INDEXCOL -> how to create number of duplicated values from 8 columns

FROM (table2 INNER JOIN Different_table ON (table2.ColH = Different_table.ColH) AND (table2.ColA = Different_table.ColA) AND (table2.ColE = Different_table.ColE) AND (table2.ColD = Different_table.ColD) AND (table2.ColB = Different_table.ColB) AND (table2.ColC = Different_table.ColC) AND (table2.Kod = Different_table.Kod)) LEFT JOIN tblCodes ON table2.ColC = tblCodes.ColC
```

Comment: Show us both sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, no images.) Also show us your current query attempt. (BTW, no need for 8 columns here, 3 or 4 will do fine. Take a look at [mcve].)

Comment: Hey, not as comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Thank you for help :) After more investigations I realized that my idea is wrong. I'm not 100 sure that data in both tables are in the same order. I need to make indx more complicated by adding more columns into it. Or something else